# Galera Async Multimaster Backup

Tags: mariadb, galera

I am just configuring a Galera 10.1.14 cluster and i want to set the Async replica from two different clusters.

```
Cluster 1 -> Data Schema A \
                            ==(WAN)==> MariaDB 10.1.14 DRS Async Node
Cluster 2 -> Data Schema B /
```

But AFAIK on the DRS Async Node can be configured only ONE master at a time so, every cluster as to be syncronized to a DRS node.
If there any way to sync to clusters to the same DRS node??

Thanks!